# Can I recover a blockchain transaction to a phishing address

Tags: addresses, phishing

I was scammed and sent 3 eth to a phishing address.

0x2ed31556f20db283569ae040d6968f65efa240ca a.k.a (Fake_Phishing4397)

It is possible to recover my losses? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to recover it unless you are able to get access to the private key of the phishing account.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Transactions are irreversible. The certainty is a feature in the context of an honest transaction, like cash that doesn't simply vaporize.

A little more nuance.

The threshold support level for a transaction-reversal is impractical. The 51% attack is a well-known "attack vector". In theory, if you can overpower 50% minus 1 of the total network hashing power you can change history, but that is an enormous investment and, in all likelihood will only lead to the other possibility ...

If you can gain the political support of a faction representing 50% plus 1 of the total mining power, you might be able to get a protocol change in which the significant difference is everyone agrees your transaction did not occur.

Both possibilities have a cost that is incomparable to the loss, so neither is a practical solution.

As Shane pointed out, probably the most likely but still out-of-reach solution is to gain access to the account that phished the funds, assuming the funds haven't already moved.

Hope it helps.